# Unable to retrieve custom attribute after enabling "Use Flat Catalog Product"

Tags: magento-1.9, flat-catalog

I have a custom attribute for the product, Which is a Multi-select. I created this attribute with php script as shown below. The attribute's "Used in Product Listing" is set to true. But im unable to access this on front-end.

```
$installer = new Mage_Sales_Model_Mysql4_Setup;

    $attributeLabel = 'Choose Active Product Store';
    $attributeCode  = 'active_stores';
    $attributeGroup = 'General';
    $attributeOrder  = 100;

    $attributeOptions2 = array(
        'label'                      => $attributeLabel,
        'input'                      => 'multiselect',
        'type'                       => 'text',
        'backend'                    => 'eav/entity_attribute_backend_array',
        'frontend'                   => null,
        'source'                     => 'storeSwitcher/product_attribute_source_store',
        'global'                     => Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Attribute::SCOPE_GLOBAL,
        'required'                   => false,
        'user_defined'               => false,
        'required'                   => true,
        'class'                      => null,
        'unique'                     => false,
        'searchable'                 => false,
        'filterable'                 => false,
        'comparable'                 => false,
        'visible_on_front'           => true,
        'is_configurable'            => false,
        'visible'                    => true,
        'default'                   => 'none',
    );

    $installer->updateAttribute(
        Mage_Catalog_Model_Product::ENTITY,
        $attributeCode,
        $attributeOptions2, $attributeCode
    );


    foreach ($attributeSets as $attributeSet) {
        $installer->addAttributeToSet(
            Mage_Catalog_Model_Product::ENTITY, $attributeSet,
            $attributeGroup, $attributeCode, $attributeOrder
        );
    }
```

i cannot filter the product collections based on this attribute.
When i checked the catalog_product_flat_xx table i cannot find the column for this attribute!

**Magento 1.9.2.4 CE**

Comment: add `used_in_product_listing=1`

Comment: I am Still waiting for an advice :(

Answer (score 0):

Add

```
'used_in_product_listing' => 1
```

in

```
$attributeOptions2 = array(
        'label'                      => $attributeLabel,
        'input'                      => 'multiselect',
        'type'                       => 'text',
        'backend'                    => 'eav/entity_attribute_backend_array',
        'frontend'                   => null,
        'source'                     => 'storeSwitcher/product_attribute_source_store',
        'global'                     => Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Attribute::SCOPE_GLOBAL,
        'required'                   => false,
        'user_defined'               => false,
        'required'                   => true,
        'class'                      => null,
        'unique'                     => false,
        'searchable'                 => false,
        'filterable'                 => false,
        'comparable'                 => false,
        'visible_on_front'           => true,
        'is_configurable'            => false,
        'visible'                    => true,
        'default'                   => 'none',
    );
```

Comment: added 'used_in_product_listing' => 1. But still the same problem